# Why does (0 < 5 < 2) result true in C++?

Tags: c++, math, boolean, boolean-logic

The following code `std::cout << (0 < 5 < 2);` outputs `1` (true) to the console, even though mathematically speaking, `5 < 2` is false. What is the logic behind this?

Hypothesis: This is because `0 < 5` is calculated as 1, therefore `0 < 5 < 2` is calculated as `1 < 2`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: Correct. It is evaluated left to right. Use parentheses for separate evaluation

Comment: I didn't know `bool` to `int` counted as an integer promotion that could be part of the [usual arithmetic conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion). Does a `bool` primitive count as a bitfield of type _Bool?

Comment: `0 < 5` evaluates to `true`, as does `true < 2`. `std::cout << true` writes "1" unless the flag `std::ios_base::boolalpha` is set on `std::cout`

Answer (score 0):

You have answered the question yourself, you are 100% correct.  Evaluation is done on the basis of precedence. Might help you:-[C++ operators Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Precedence and ORDER in the case of ties.